# Get the last element of an array to remove comma from it

Tags: php, foreach

I have a simple function that displays values ​​followed by a comma.

```
if ( $hasCoAuthors ) :
        
    foreach ( $co_authors as $co_author ) :

        $coAuthorDisplayName = $co_author->display_name;
        $coAuthor = '<span class="co-author">' . $coAuthorDisplayName . '</span>, ';

        echo $coAuthor;

    endforeach;

endif;
```

How to get the last value to remove the comma from it?

I added this function:

```
function endKey( $array ) {

    end( $array );
    return key( $array );

}
```

Then I added this in my function:

```
if ( endKey( $co_authors ) ) :
    $coAuthor = '<span class="co-author">' . $coAuthorDisplayName . '</span>';
endif;
```

But it doesn't work, it removes commas from all values.

Comment: Determining that you are in the _first_ loop iteration is much easier (for example via a simple boolean flag) - so do that, and then output the comma _before_ the span, but only if it is not the first loop iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing value each time which is unnecessay, concat them into one string variable then print it once loop ended by using `rtrim()` to remove last comma.

You need to correct loop code like below:

```
if ( $hasCoAuthors ) :
   $coAuthor = '';
   foreach ( $co_authors as $co_author ) :
      $coAuthor .= '<span class="co-author">' . $co_author->display_name . '</span>, ';
   endforeach;
   echo rtrim($coAuthor, ',');
endif;
```

Comment: I didn't know which one to choose lol it works perfectly! Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

Build the html in a string, then trim the final comma using `trim()` before echoing it once when the loop is complete.

```
if ( $hasCoAuthors ) :
    $coAuthor = '';
    foreach ( $co_authors as $co_author ) :
        $coAuthor .= '<span class="co-author">' . $co_author->display_name . '</span>, ';
    endforeach;
    echo rtrim($coAuthor, ',');
endif;
```

Or as @CBroe suggests

```
if ( $hasCoAuthors ) :
    $coAuthor = '';
    foreach ( $co_authors as $k => $co_author ) :
        if ($k > 0 ) {
            $coAuthor .= ','
        }
        $coAuthor .= '<span class="co-author">' . $co_author->display_name . '</span>';
    endforeach;
    echo $coAuthor;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

If keys are numeric (0, 1, 2, etc.), you can use simply this code to add `,` to 2nd and others.

```
if ( $hasCoAuthors ) :
        
    foreach ( $co_authors as $key => $co_author ) :

 
        $coAuthor = '';
        if ($key > 0) {
            $coAuthor = ', ';
        }

        $coAuthorDisplayName = $co_author->display_name;
        $coAuthor .= '<span class="co-author">' . $coAuthorDisplayName . '</span>, ';
 
        echo $coAuthor;

    endforeach;

endif;
```

The second way is to put values into `array` and use `implode`.

```
if ( $hasCoAuthors ) :
    
    $coAuthors = [];        
    foreach ( $co_authors as $key => $co_author ) :

        $coAuthorDisplayName = $co_author->display_name;
        $coAuthors[] = '<span class="co-author">' . $coAuthorDisplayName . '</span>';

    endforeach;

    echo implode(', ', $coAuthors);

endif;
```